# How to directly upload a Jupyter notebook from Local Machine onto Google Collab? Is there a way to do this?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Currently I have the Jupyter notebook on my local machine. It will be helpful if I could directly export it to Google Collab rather than copy pasting it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me, I go to https://drive.google.com

Then upload the notebook file to folder 'Colab Notebooks', then open it from there.

Another, simpler way, is the go to the menu in Colab

- File > Upload notebook...
- Select the notebook file to upload

Now (nov 2018) another simpler way is to click open the left pane. Click File tab, then click upload.

Comment: Thanks. Approach 1 works for me. But approach 2 gets stuck as uploading and doesn't complete.